If-none-match header filtered upstream to my firebase function?
I'd like to implement ETag support on one my google cloud function (deployed throught Firebase) but it looks like If-None-Match headers gets filtered upstream to the cloud function call.
I'm using express in my cloud function, and I did:
const app = express()
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(`In app.use() middleware, headers: ${JSON.stringify(req.headers)}`)
  next();
})


and when looking at logs, I can't see If-None-Match header in the available headers list.
If, clientside, I replace this header with X-If-None-Match, then I can see it listed in the cloud function log.
If possible, I'd like to avoid to change this header name as some clients already started calling my API, and this is becoming complicated to ask them to change their header names (to a non-standard one) only because Google is filtering it at some point in the infra/network appliance.
Is there any configuration somewhere to prevent filtering of this header in the google infrastructure ?
PS: I'm using old Node JS 18 (1st gen) functions. If someone having Node JS 2nd gen function can check if on 2nd gen this is working, it would be another good argument for me to migrate to 2nd gen.
PS2: After a lot of debugging, I discovered the root cause of the problem.
I am using Firebase Hosting "human friendly" URLs to access my firebase functions: when I use those Firebase Hosting base-url, If-None-Match header gets filtered out, whilst if I use the us-central1-<project>.cloudfunctions.net url, they remain available at the request level.
Looks like the only workaround is to use a custom X-If-None-Match header if I want to keep using my firebase hosting urls :(

I'm unable to repro your issue with Cloud Run (Cloud Functions gen2) (with a Golang server that enumerates) headers

Thanks DazWilkin. On my side, I just tried to upgrade to NodeJS Cloud functions gen2 but am still not seeing if-none-match amongst available request headers

Curious. I'm not much of a Node.JS developer but I'll try to repro using your code.

I deployed something similar to your code using Cloud Run. Added an If-None-Match header to a curl request against it and see the header in the server's logs.

After a lot of debugging, I found the problem : I am using firebase hosting "human friendly" URLs to access my firebase functions. When I use firebase hosting base url, If-None-Match header gets filtered out, whilst if I use the https://us-central1-.cloudfunctions.net url, they remain available in the request. Looks like the only workaround is to use a custom X-If-None-Match header if I want to keep using my firebase hosting urls :(
